# HtmlPurifier and pre tag content

Tags: htmlpurifier

Does anyone know how should I configure HtmlPurifier to ignore content within <pre> tag?
Currently I have something like this:

```
require_once('HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank'));
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
$config->set('Output.FlashCompat', true);
$config->set('Filter.Custom',  array( new HTMLPurifier_Filter_SafeIframe() ));
$config->set('Attr.EnableID', true);
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'href*', 'URI');
$def->addAttribute('a', 'rel', 'CDATA');
$objPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
return $objPurifier->purify($string);
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it?
I would be grateful if you post how you did.

Answer (score 1):

Try [%Core.HiddenElements](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.HiddenElements).

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding

```
pre[class]
```

to the property

```
HTML.Allowed
```